# javascriptmvc folder structure with asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, javascriptmvc

It seems to me the first biggest hurdle of fitting javascriptmvc into asp.net mvc, is the folder structure.  Has anyone adapted the asp.net mvc folder structure to serve up content files from the folder structure javascriptmvc expects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using `routes.IgnoreRoute("javascriptmvc-3.0.5/{*pathInfo}");` in your route definitions things should work as expected.

Comment: I don't this this answered the question. Could you elaborate on the folder structure of an asp.net mvc web app that uses javascriptmvc?

Comment: Downvoting the answered question 10 months later? I could explain it but now I won't